# Does an irrational number $C$ exist such that $C \cdot \sqrt 2 \in \Bbb{Q}$?

Tags: irrational-numbers

Does an irrational number $C$ exist such that $C \cdot \sqrt 2 \in \Bbb{Q}$, where $\sqrt2 \not\mid C$?

I just thought of this, I'm trying to find answers that aren't of the form $C=a\sqrt2, a\in\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: What does $\sqrt 2\nmid C$ mean?

Comment: $\sqrt2$ does not divide $C$.

Comment: What does ‘$ \sqrt{2} $ does not divide $ C $’ mean?

Comment: @BerrickCalebFillmore That $\frac{C} {\sqrt 2}  \not \in \Bbb {Z}$

Comment: Well, according to your definition, $ \sqrt{2} \nmid \dfrac{1}{2} \sqrt{2} $, but $ \dfrac{1}{2} \sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{2} = 1 $, and as the others have explained, it isn’t possible to find a $ C \notin \Bbb{Q} \cdot \sqrt{2} $.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $C\cdot\sqrt 2\in\mathbb Q$, then $C\cdot\sqrt 2=q$ for some $q\in\mathbb Q$, hence $C=\frac q{\sqrt 2}=\frac q2\cdot\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously not: if $C \cdot \sqrt 2 \in \mathbb Q$, then there exist integers $p,q$ such that $C \cdot \sqrt 2 = \frac p q$, i.e. $C=\frac p {2q} \sqrt 2$, which is exactly what you said you do not want.